# Interface-less login to login.microsoftonline.com

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, active-directory, httpwebrequest, fiddler

This issue has kept me busy for days now, so I might just as well post it here... searching in other topics has brought me far, but I'm not there yet.

### Background

My job is to automate tests in the browser: I make use of Selenium and .NET to handle this. One of our clients uses Active Directory for logging in on the web application. Logging in again for every test takes a lot of time (a new session is started for each test), so I'm trying to speed this phase up by writing a class that will login beforehand, without the browser.

By using Fiddler, I managed to reproduce most of the webrequests in code. Still, I don't work with custom web requests often, so I easily overlook possible issues. Something goes wrong in the last step, where I try to retrieve the AppServiceAuthSession cookie. I'll use a picture to illustrate:
[image]
On the left, there is the web request I make using my code. On the right, there is the web request I get when using the browser.

The Nonce cookie has its value, headers are correct... the only difference here is the "Expect" header instead of the "Connection" header, but that happens because I disabled the "AllowAutoRedirect" property for the request (I don't get to see this request in Fiddler if I keep it enabled).

Next, here comes the content of both requests, since that's hard to show by using the Fiddler interface.

Code request:

```
code=AQABAAIAAABHh4kmS_aKT5XrjzxRAtHzZ08Y3xv2A4HxumqfAbR5iIBFEbbm6oYUq5sdHF72ybOkXFz33XVW5uXvuq-Tiz43zQ7y08bAhGH-aR_3HEpugBMAX_Op4O0Z4RjMKOLyd5b-VNVhjqv_CRmgHTEhYnxubjNyaG-5Vsuo7YRa3jXFybBheb73Erp7CDYFCQ-dFjgNAEHEbzrfE64dGVvHCCr-rvpHCTJfW55eYE9l68d7rryVfqC8dX7wplr7A3G8ySS84Tb9_hYxA61L_fQEm22NehWGNKw_MwXWNsIONtwiRd5LQD95iXYwjCw9J1p-WoZw9p6228r8YOuBVJA0k22O_zjqvKGUkVEyVWvAZZvDSO26_m-uuz7ql52ZTfBhmOfF8iXfdgeUPUqSXmTmNtL0LAOgiYKt4DyH1TbgAN2ox-sVcFp0k7bmjE81h0yiY8RgR-a2aONvuIpSR1Dx7VG-1wkllQAkYGV8zMoahs0EVRiDdOEQwwvkegALZNaU_ROKkbxj-H71h7lffkLlZoeM1lQFwgcVyB1_kV04iZKg2x5-VxHRYCDCNdeaxuaZD5dOrxIh_Y6SfQK-VBWsDB1C_i76QQpFI2c-7oxFNn7RLCU5gw7iv8k31ry2-hKSfhcU6LtN--t-eW73ADu0cW9juh1zzgzXAPXz0FqNyh07SyRawPqir9jdZ4GlgU4r-Imm41n4b7LH_nYixE1q-JNTm7TlawW3Xe7i28QMx95wPGlqyYl0PAo0VMwMPgoG3Zi-5BiEFi31qOxCMJNbXWi-YOMMcV3W5-sNbYA44mOUoYnz0hny-PlvKFwTL9RLBxkgAA&
id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkZTaW11RnJGTm9DMHNKWEdtdjEzbk5aY2VEYyIsImtpZCI6IkZTaW11RnJGTm9DMHNKWEdtdjEzbk5aY2VEYyJ9.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.xcuSefb-pr21z53eoirQTj3nptW95rQ0RnsxkF6B436Z16bI826UK4wYLvjGl8NrXYV1-sJhlUTUuX31p90GxJthUV1tbzsvFUwNk8f9DJgKls-31X78fNbChkuNDIS9Tj6Lj0cPOlZaC6U8TXYaNsef8qURtvtXzPt7Td1t6rfvuJL29pnow0We7u-eqUR8_TDD9PzY82BdYSbfIn4X-cOw4F79O-OAce9zRebX3V1Cr53gizMUIKKDWlS8fdwKnpdluAgZup-r6RJa7c_ui0NB2REao-PxixkvO-PuCtEfLhRnbRAprVa6ggMlCrtN6Uf7EmLRGLNBGHbl379vgg&
state=redir%3d%252Flogin%252Fcheck&
session_state=4dcbbba5-e8a5-4ad7-9ba9-28f6af570ead
```

Browser request:

```
code=AQABAAIAAABHh4kmS_aKT5XrjzxRAtHzZT_hGoYPGfSq8uoVwxawNGgqfV8j3-WdO_yha1uD2rspKWZmKjbV4j3YQmg4IQOdNBKzWDYTAST-Shag2D2Ih9EHMThyu7ncE_XRSBDOb_f05q3WCKYtF5ki5VVFcd8Li029KFwEjjutGw4k-_GfPe1rym5CXRvqQzj0wGUN4Q3ndwqrcNXsdvGG6wEXbiTJ8_3aSyuAAsHBMr1l23fjJRe-CKfr7EqKDZLzm_2H6L0MODy_mWkrD715CjU2_mUb1YQ__6MZvhHss41BFPcL3zyK2oh7Z668dJMEK495MhKFt-NPUFUPXsUNwK1fP4F-tdmBIY39BL9vDxzynmcF5A63yb8q3m0CgJOZ0i1aobe1iEX75sNXjIa2385yFw08lmkVJFj9GccvIE5ak4Zi6sdjWhEtS9TyKXc5uBtKxJCYIy52avI6bUAyc5-Xq0amik0Q75wuLK0bSoeIwBofKuJnoHfl1o3_7N2uSZ_2dJx5zPW9VxRz4e6u-mkmDu9F5lK42zo3al8c03zKHhLkTVRx08JV7JZuqpLznz5JFEHp1QUq-KeYNdMXsngPZW3VEegSyu6VGYwvbmL07GYTZ3KWi-dGxej88KvobZF3O40rfISThS4gVpnFoH7UQs_RE_TEjRvUraFBUhjE-1EUd7WXl6NsxQwGO0Uw7W87ZqlY4G-JhN39MOdm4v9UZELmeZph87PWqqy9-6h1pK8wrH8S98HqV1q3DUR68Ue-zCSvV9hgxrkSnPtFDTfCgtOvpNj14GUesMi8L0XPa6DsO0hj27_A1T0STGSHMGg8QMcgAA&
id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkZTaW11RnJGTm9DMHNKWEdtdjEzbk5aY2VEYyIsImtpZCI6IkZTaW11RnJGTm9DMHNKWEdtdjEzbk5aY2VEYyJ9.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.eT25sB0q7a5nEPBS5z2WVFHohBdzgioj6rd5DOMlb30dp1mIAVgvRZxSJhybB6RuHOl86LTkcyH4qzXl8uQ9fq8hapZUdJ2sDDqvk-PmcIWp_Ar6Gyo--4DtUxu7quIe-JaP_HyN_lsNbm0Gxut2VkZuHmCaiBxRriosP2FRg2GyKO75P6V7r0EPmQnS_4HA0WhEUmqNBzrZnbMV4rkc4FkLoMSLgJN69XdBMCQfsnhVcDWFPGj_Q79vlSbSq17Y7EPxn5phkrLGfZGMQj6CNHSzeT76LxR4txUu16QEQLLHckw2aSsESQ8SPFXwk794jEuyFIoFPrGg75hv4XxC7Q&
state=redir%3D%252Flogin%252Fcheck&
session_state=d897cb81-a5db-41f2-8852-8c18a82d36ab
```

### Issue

As visible in the picture, the web request gets a response without AppServiceAuthSession and is redirected to the login.windows.net location. The normal browser request is different: it is successful at this point.

### Question

Does anyone have a clue on what goes wrong here, or on how to debug it successfully? I triple-checked the input of the previous requests as well, but they all seem identical to the ones given to the browser. Even just a pointer in general might help... I'm getting a bit lost here. If more info is needed, just let me know. Thanks in advance!

### Extra information

The code, in case it helps (censored where needed):

```
class Login
{
    static CookieContainer cookiesNonce = new CookieContainer();
    static CookieContainer cookiesA = new CookieContainer();
    static CookieContainer cookiesB = new CookieContainer();

    public static void DoLogin()
    {
        // CLIENTNAME-api, request for login with redirect
        var url = @"https://CLIENTNAME-api.CLIENTNAME-dev.nl/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_url=/login/check";
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Accept = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36";
        request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            cookiesNonce.Add(response.Cookies);
            cookiesA.Add(response.Cookies);

            request = WebRequest.Create(response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.Location]) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Accept = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36";
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Host = @"login.windows.net";
            request.CookieContainer = cookiesA;
        }

        string clientrequestid = "";
        string authorizeUrl = "";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            cookiesA = new CookieContainer();
            cookiesA.Add(response.Cookies);
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            var jsonRegEx = new Regex(@"\$Config=(.*?)(?<=\});");
            var temp = jsonRegEx.Match(html).Groups[1].ToString() ;

            var dict = JObject.Parse(temp);
            var hpgrequestid = response.Headers["x-ms-request-id"];
            var canary = GetValue(dict, "apiCanary");
            clientrequestid = GetClientRequestId(dict);

            authorizeUrl = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.Location];

            // Request to microsoft online by credentials
            url = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType";
            request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = @"POST";
            request.CookieContainer = cookiesB;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("hpgrequestid", hpgrequestid);
            request.Headers.Add("canary", canary);
            request.Headers.Add("client-request-id", clientrequestid);
            request.Headers.Add("hpgact", "1800");
            request.Headers.Add("hpgid", "1104");
            request.Referer = response.ResponseUri.ToString(); ;
            var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            var buffer = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(@"{""username"":""user@COMPANYNAME.nl"",""isOtherIdpSupported"":true,""checkPhones"":false,""isRemoteNGCSupported"":false,""isCookieBannerShown"":true,""isFidoSupported"":false,""originalRequest"":""rQIIAZ2Qv08UQRzFd26PDaCJxBCD3RUQE83szM7N7s1eQoGCGjEhXAwQLch35wc33rK7zK6i_Ak2YGFjZSwvVlbGP4FGav8CYyOhsvTU-A_YvPeq93l5N_0ojPqLIsmyJJUKi5QLzBMDOFW9GKegMq2MYHFs3NXZOf7jvH3x5dX68Rs2OKYlHaPesGmquk_ISBeFw1DZ8G9S-nlY5CSEZ82Q5OWeLQiAIhLyPAM5-oTQGULfEBq3yITN41iprmCKc8MzxikFIWXSS6SJk11GI0G7LKJp3OvSr60rGyuTVvZbSmeP9EVrxpRuf7cq6-atf81pZd3yErv7BztxOdRyNPav_9u656Aahoe2UOVhHRa6-egvRiBBgJE4hkRjrkDjlAPHkWBUCcplpLNTf76sdGFVp3Klsbnu6H2w-VkbfW9fpn5_enp2zlvwOt7PNno_NfmrXrp08OHJ7dXX714ObnQD73SKkFuDxxUMDF2xxc7W_c2No3zdwc7q5kPxtLmztq22WP3i0ba992BtmfWjkwCdBMF54H2e-d-rfwE1""}");
            reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
        }



        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            cookiesB.Add(response.Cookies);
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            // Request to sts.COMPANYNAME.nl
            url = @"https://sts.COMPANYNAME.nl/adfs/ls/wia?client-request-id=" + clientrequestid + @"&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=LoginOptions%3D3%26estsredirect%3d2%26estsrequest%3drQIIAZ2QPU8UQRjHd26PDZwmEEOIdldATDSzOzs7uze7CYkoqBETwsUAwYLMzgs33t7uOrt4ykewAQsbK2N5sbIyfgQaqSmtjI2EytJF4xewef5P9X_53bJ9108WaZSmUcwFpDGhkESKwVj0QhgzkUqhKA5DZa515sjP8_bF19frR29x_wgVaAJ6g7ouq8TzhjLPDWSldv9-Qr5w88xz2UE98LJiX-ceY8LjLMtSxoefATgF4DsAk5bXZJMwFCKgWBCiSIoJQoxyHvUirsJoDyOfogD7KA57ATprzW6sNK748hRGH8qL1owqzGivLKr6nb1gpNBmeQnf_xPbKB9IPpzYN_513TesHLhjnYtiXLm5rD_Ziz7jjDLFYcgiCYlgEsaEEehTjARFhPsyPbHni1LmWnRLUyidya4cMZ19s2fNQSrz0Z1RYzJuZp-2wY_2VWQn09OdOeu61bV-tcGHqYZgtXTl-cend1ffvH_Vvxk41smU593u75asr9CKzne2Hm5uHGbrhu2sbj6mz-p7a9tiC1cvn2zrB4_WlnHiHzvg2HHOHevLzP_CP-vMXyKFKIDY76I4CXESkN3f0&cbcxt=&username=user%40COMPANYNAME.nl&mkt=&lc=";
            request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            cookiesB = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer = cookiesB;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            request.Referer = response.ResponseUri.ToString(); ;
            request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36";
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            cookiesB.Add(response.Cookies);
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='wresult']");
            var value = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
            var decode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
            var wresult = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(decode);
            node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='wctx']");
            value = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
            decode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
            var wctx = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(decode);
            reader.Close();

            // Logging in to microsoft online
            url = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?client-request-id=" + clientrequestid;
            request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.CookieContainer = cookiesB;
            request.Referer = response.ResponseUri.ToString(); ;
            request.Method = @"POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36";
            request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://sts.COMPANYNAME.nl");
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            var buffer = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(@"wa=wsignin1.0&wresult=" + wresult + @"&wctx=" + wctx);
            reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            cookiesB = new CookieContainer();
            cookiesB.Add(response.Cookies);
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            reader.Close();

            var state = GetValue(doc, "state");
            var code = GetValue(doc, "code");
            var idtoken = GetValue(doc, "id_token");
            var session_state = GetValue(doc, "session_state");

            // Callback to .auth/login
            url = @"https://CLIENTNAME-api.CLIENTNAME-dev.nl/.auth/login/aad/callback";
            request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = @"POST";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var cookie = cookiesNonce.GetCookies(new Uri("https://CLIENTNAME-api.CLIENTNAME-dev.nl"))["Nonce"];
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://login.microsoftonline.com");
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36";
            request.Accept = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Referer = response.ResponseUri.ToString(); ;
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", @"gzip, deflate, br");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", @"en-US,en;q=0.9");
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            var buffer = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(@"code=" + code + @"&id_token=" + idtoken + @"&state=" + state + "&session_state=" + session_state);
            reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var appServiceAuthSession = response.Cookies["AppServiceAuthSession"].ToString();

            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    private static string GetValue(HtmlDocument doc, string name)
    {
        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='" + name + @"']");
        var value = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
        var decode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
        var result = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(decode);
        return result;
    }

    private static string GetValue(string key, string input, string delimiter)
    {
        var value = RegexHelper.GetValueForKey(input, key, delimiter);
        return value;
    }

    private static string GetValue(JObject container, string key)
    {
        string value = (string)container[key];
        return value;
    }

    private static string GetClientRequestId(JObject container)
    {
        var obj = container["desktopSsoConfig"];
        var value = (string)obj["iwaEndpointUrlFormat"];
        var content = value.Split('&');
        var id = content[content.Length - 1].Replace("client-request-id=", "");
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @ToneŠkoda Sadly enough, not yet. We worked around it by logging in once using Selenium and then navigating to /.auth/me. Then we capture the token using javascript and use that token in every following browser session. I will post a more detailed description of the work-around when I have more time next week.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID connect is intentionally unspecific about the nature of the user authentication. The premise is that the authentication service will render whatever authentication it needs to the user, and if this has been satisfactory, will issue a short lived code which is redirected to the application. The application then uses that code to obtain a token.

There are other flows for authenticating non-user facing application like services. That might not help you though if you need to emulate a user logon.

As you are on Selenium already, why not have it enter the test user credentials into the ui presented in a web browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but at least a useful workaround in our case:

1. *Login by using the browser.*
2. *Navigate to the auth/me page.*

Example: let's say the home url I had to use was https://company.company-dev.nl. I adjusted the url to https://company-api.company-dev.nl/.auth/me and navigated there.

3. *Retrieve the access token from the html.*

[image]

To read the token, I used the following code:

```
private string ConvertToken(string html)
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var timeout = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    dynamic obj = null;

    while (obj == null && DateTime.Now < timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            obj = (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Firefox occasionally bugs out if its JSON viewer kicks in too early, so use the according elements if needed
            var element = Driver.FindElementById("rawdata-tab");
            Driver.ClickElement(element);
            var text = Driver.FindElementByClassName("data").Text;
            obj = (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
        }
    }
    return obj[0]["access_token"].ToString();
}
```

4. *Save the token.*
5. *When the next test starts, append the token to the home url.*

   ```
   {
       NavigateToUrl(HomeUrl + @"login/" + Token);
   }
   ```

Example: https://company.company-dev.nl/#/login/eyJ0eXAiOiandareallylonglineofcharactershere

This way, you can make only one test login, while the others will use the token generated by the first one. You have to play around with some other things as well (using the token while testing in parallel, dealing with token timeouts, etc.), but this is the core of the workaround.